# Taurus equivalent "Run Thread Groups Consecutively"

Tags: automation, jmeter, taurus

Given a single (.jmx) file - what is the equivalent to the following configuration in the image seen below.

**Taurus (.yml) Configuration**

```
included-configs:  
- Variables-local.yml # the file containing your properties definitions

execution:
  iterations: 1
  concurrency: 1
  scenario:
    script: AutomatedTests.jmx

modules:
  jmeter:
    class: bzt.modules.jmeter.JMeterExecutor
    path: C:/JMeter
    properties:
      jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush: 'true'

reporting:
- module: junit-xml
  filename: TEST-Taurus.xml
```

**Image Reference to JMeter UI Functionality**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend you ["execution"](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/) block and add all the modifications you want to make to the original JMeter script there like:

```
included-configs:
  - Variables-local.yml # the file containing your properties definitions

execution:
  iterations: 1
  concurrency: 1
  scenario:
    script: AutomatedTests.jmx
    modifications:
      set-prop:
        "Test Plan>TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups": true

modules:
  jmeter:
    class: bzt.modules.jmeter.JMeterExecutor
    path: C:/JMeter
    properties:
      jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush: 'true'

reporting:
  - module: junit-xml
    filename: TEST-Taurus.xml
```

More information:

- [Modifications for Existing Scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: Where can I find a list of these properties? I am not the original creator of the JMX. I am simply automating it.

Comment: In the .jmx file itself